# How to use the function `pj_geodetic_to_geocentric` in boost library?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-geometry

In `boost/geometry/srs/projections/impl/pj_transform.hpp`, I found two functions `pj_geodetic_to_geocentric` and `pj_geocentric_to_geodetic`, the function declarations are below:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename Range>
inline int pj_geocentric_to_geodetic( T const& a, T const& es,
                                      Range & range );
template <typename T, typename Range>
inline int pj_geodetic_to_geocentric( T const& a, T const& es,
                                      Range & range );
```

each function is manually converted from PROJ4, I am confused, how to use the function?
The variable `Range &range`, how to pass a variable in the function?

I do not know how to use it!! Help me please!

Comment: What do you mean by "the function is manually converted from PROJ4"?

Answer (score 0):

Those functions are used by `pj_transform` function. It is not clear what you want to compute but you should try to use `pj_transform` function instead or since your are using the Boost Geometry adaptation of `proj4` the `transform` function. Since there is no documentation on this functionality I recommend reading the [tests](https://github.com/boostorg/geometry/tree/develop/test/srs).